# Is there any possibility to make circle crop in PhotoEditor sdk?

Tags: crop, geometry, photoeditorsdk

For the time being photoeditor sdk provides an ability to customize crop ratios. But, I wonder if there any possibility to make a circle crop? Or, at least, is there any chance I can customize crop controls view?

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for circle crops or customized cropping masks yet and as this is not supported by our renderer, you won't be able to add such functionality by customizing the crop controls. Sorry!